# How can i get a id element from an object which is nested within an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

How can i retrieve just the id value to use as a key value from an array of objects

so right now it looks like this

```
0{id:1 , description:null. etc...}
1{id:34 , description:null. etc...}
2{id:122 , escription:null. etc...}
3{id:14 , description:null. etc...}
4{id:654 , description:null. etc...}
```

How can i just retrieve the values of the id such as 1,34,122,14,654

Comment: `arr.map(({id}) => id)`

Answer (score 0):

I think what your looking for is map, it takes a callback and loops through it and creates a new array with the return value of the callback of each item

In this case you could do it like

```js
arr.map(obj => obj.id);
```

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)